# form multi select without multi?

Tags: html, html-select

Is there a way to have a non dropdown select (like a multi) without the multi select functionality?
Basically I have a file list I want as an actual list and not a dropdown, but with the ability to only select the one file at a time.

I have set it up as a multi and tried to disable the ctrl, alt & shift keypresses but to no avail, and that also seems like a hacky way to do it which I don't really want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you are looking for attribute `size`

```
<!-- Renders a classic select -->
<select name="text">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected="">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<!-- Renders a select with 3 visible options (also called a "scrolled list box") and no multiselect functionality -->
<select name="text" size="3">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected="">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: Brilliant! thanks for that, I figured I had missed something obvious but my google failed me